# Time dimension name for more than one date field

Tags: ssas, pivot-table

I have a time dimension (named Time), server dimension type, which is related (in the DIMENSION USAGE) with the field **TransactionDate** of  fact table. That dimension is named **Time (Transaction Date)** on the Dimension Usage window. Moreover, I created two other dimensions in this window to point to other date fields in the fact table: **DueDate** (named **Time (Expiration date)** and **DocumentDate** (named **Time (Document date)**). The problem is if I access the data from an Excel PivotTable, the first dimension is correctly identified with the name **Time - Date Transaction** but the other two are identified with the same name and it is impossible to know wich field time is related (whether that of **DueDate** or **DocumentDate**). The three dimensions are identical, the only difference are the names assigned and the field to which they relate. Does anyone know how to identify them correctly from Excel so that they can differentiate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the "Dimension Usage" tab, where you added DueDate and DocumentDate, you can rename it to whatever name you want. This is SSAS's feature to handle role playing dimensions.